# How to update coordinates for triangle?

Tags: java, javafx

I haven't found what i'm looking for when i was searching. That being said, it might just be me looking with the wrong keywords. I'm sorry if this will become a duplicate thread, as it's not my intention.

I have made a method that creates a rectangle based on mouse events. I'm using it to drag on the screen and it checks if there is instances of shape inside of it. If there is shapes inside of it, i'm checking to see if the whole shape is inside of the rectangle, using the contains(Point2d point2d) method. Ofcourse i have calculated the max and min for x respectivly y, and put those into Point2d:s so i can use that method.

Everything works fine for Circle, i can even move the circle and everything still works as it suppoused to. The problem comes when i'm trying to detect a triangle. I have made triangles of javafx polygons. It works as it suppoused to, as long as i don't move it. I'm thinking i'm just moving it on the screen, but it's still at the default place.

**My questing is, is there a way to update the triangles coordinates on the backend? i'm thinking maybe i could use the getPoints().replaceAll() method, but i can't figure out how to make it work.**

My triangle class looks like this at the moment:

```
package model;

import interfaces.Triangle;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class LargeTriangle implements Triangle {

    private Polygon triangle;


    public LargeTriangle(){
        triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.getPoints().addAll(
                400.0,200.0,
                200.0, 400.0,
                600.0, 400.0
        );
    }


    @Override
    public void setColor(Paint color) {
        triangle.setFill(color);
    }

    @Override
    public Polygon getTriangle() {
        return triangle;
    }


    @Override
    public void move(MouseEvent e) {

        Bounds bounds = this.getTriangle().getLayoutBounds();
        this.getTriangle().relocate(e.getSceneX()-bounds.getWidth()/2.0,e.getSceneY()-
                bounds.getHeight()/2.0);

    }

    @Override
    public void delete() {

    }

    @Override
    public void group() {

    }

    @Override
    public void ungroup() {

    }
}
```

and here is the methods i'm using for this in my Main class that extends Application:

```
public void startProgram(){
        insideFigures = new ArrayList<>();
        rectangle = new Rectangle();
        window = (Stage) btnStart.getScene().getWindow();
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/fxmls/mainWindow.fxml"));
            mainWindowRoot = loader.load();
            mainWindow = loader.getController();
            mainWindow.setup(mainWindow);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        window.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,e->{

            firstX = e.getX();
            firstY = e.getY();
        });

        window.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,e->{

            insideFigures.clear();
            lastX =e.getX();
            lastY =e.getY();

            PickResult pickResult = e.getPickResult();
            Node theNode = pickResult.getIntersectedNode();

            if(theNode instanceof Shape){}
            else{

                rectangle.setX(firstX);
                rectangle.setY(firstY);
                rectangle.setWidth(lastX-firstX);
                rectangle.setHeight(lastY-firstY);

                for(Node node:mainWindowRoot.getChildren()){
                    if(node instanceof Shape){
                        Shape shape = (Shape) node;
                        if(shape!= rectangle){
                            if(isInside(shape)) {
                                if (!insideFigures.contains(shape)) {
                                    insideFigures.add(shape);
                                    System.out.println("true");
                                }
                            }
                            else System.out.println("false!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        window.setScene(new Scene(mainWindowRoot,800,600));
        window.show();
    }

    public boolean isInside(Shape shape) {

        if (shape instanceof Circle) {
            Circle circle = (Circle) shape;
            Point2D circleCenter = new Point2D(circle.getCenterX(), circle.getCenterY());
            Point2D circleMaxX = new Point2D(circle.getCenterX() + circle.getRadius(), circle.getCenterY());
            Point2D circleMinX = new Point2D(circle.getCenterX() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getCenterY());
            Point2D circleMaxY = new Point2D(circle.getCenterX(), circle.getCenterY() + circle.getRadius());
            Point2D circleMinY = new Point2D(circle.getCenterX(), circle.getCenterY() - circle.getRadius());

            Bounds bounds = rectangle.getLayoutBounds();
            if (bounds.contains(circleCenter)) {
                if (bounds.getMinX() < circleMinX.getX()) {
                    if (bounds.getMaxX() > circleMaxX.getX()) {
                        if (bounds.getMinY() < circleMinY.getY()) {
                            if (bounds.getMaxY() > circleMaxY.getY()) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(shape instanceof Polygon){
            Polygon triangle = (Polygon) shape;

            Point2D triangleCenter = new Point2D(triangle.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()/2,triangle.getLayoutBounds().getHeight()/2);

            Bounds bounds = rectangle.getLayoutBounds();
            if (bounds.contains(triangleCenter)) {
                if(bounds.getMinX()<triangle.getLayoutBounds().getMinX()){
                    if(bounds.getMaxX()> triangle.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX()){
                        if(bounds.getMinY()<triangle.getLayoutBounds().getMinY()){
                            if(bounds.getMaxY()> triangle.getLayoutBounds().getMaxY()){
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            boolean returnValue = false;
            double x = 0;
            double y;
            int i=1;
            ArrayList<Point2D>polygonPoints = new ArrayList<>();
            Point2D temp;

            for(Double coord:triangle.getPoints()){
                if(i%2==1){
                    x=coord;
                }

                if(i%2==0){
                    y=coord;
                    temp = new Point2D(x,y);
                    polygonPoints.add(temp);
                }
                i++;
            }

            for (Point2D currentPoint:polygonPoints){
                if (rectangle.contains(currentPoint)) {
                    returnValue = true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and for reference, i give you the circle code that works aswell:

```
package model;

import interfaces.Circle;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;

public class LargeCircle implements Circle {

    private javafx.scene.shape.Circle circle;

    public LargeCircle(){
        circle = new javafx.scene.shape.Circle();
        circle.setRadius(50);
        circle.setCenterX(400);
        circle.setCenterY(300);

    }

    @Override
    public double getRadius() {
        return circle.getRadius();
    }

    @Override
    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        circle.setRadius(radius);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Paint color) {
        circle.setFill(color);
    }

    @Override
    public javafx.scene.shape.Circle getCircle() {
        return circle;
    }


    @Override
    public void move(MouseEvent e) {
        this.getCircle().setCenterX(e.getX());
        this.getCircle().setCenterY(e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void delete() {

    }

    @Override
    public void group() {

    }

    @Override
    public void ungroup() {

    }
}
```

thanks for helping me!

//Mozzie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out it was very simple in the end. I used

```
Bounds triangleBounds = triangle.getBoundsInParent();
```

and from that, i could keep the shape and get its current location on the screen. From that i made:

```
    Point2D triangleCenter = new Point2D(triangleBounds.getCenterX(),triangleBounds.getCenterY());
    Point2D triangleLowerRightCorner = new Point2D(triangleBounds.getMaxX(),triangleBounds.getMaxY());
    Point2D triangleLowerLeftCorner = new Point2D(triangleBounds.getMinX(),triangleBounds.getMaxY());
    Point2D triangleTopCorner = new Point2D(triangleBounds.getCenterX(),triangleBounds.getMinY());
```

and to check if it was inside:

```
    if(rectangle.contains(triangleCenter)){
        if(rectangle.contains(triangleLowerRightCorner)){
            if(rectangle.contains(triangleLowerLeftCorner)){
                if(rectangle.contains(triangleTopCorner)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Polygon::getPoints()` returns a child of `List`. So

```
triangle.getPoints().clear();
triangle.getPoints().addAll(
  <new values>
);
```

should work IMHO.

Comment: that just changes the size of the triangle. But maybe it is a stepforward as i should be able to rule out getPoints().replaceAll() as it would just do the same?